# Converting BINARY data to its equivalent BLOB (Text) value in Hive

Tags: hive, binary

We have BLOB (text) data stored in Hive as Binary .Now this needs to consumed as its equivalent text value at the SRSS server sql server reporting services.

Is there any specific function available for the above scenario?

```
BASE64( column)


select BASE64(column) from hive_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `decode(binary bin, string charset)` Decodes the first argument into a String using the provided character set (one of 'US-ASCII', 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE', 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-16'). If either argument is null, the result will also be null. (As of Hive [**0.12.0.**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2482))

[**All Hive String Functions**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions)